# searching with join table , ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have a question about searching code table reimburse and entered by username in table user.
this is form searching:

```
<%= form_tag reimburses_searchreimburse_path, method: :get do %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :reimburse, params[:reimburse] %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil%>
                    <% end %>
```

this the controller

```
 def searchreimburse
 @users = User.where("username LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:reimburse]}%")  
 @reimburses = Reimburse.all  
 @project = Project.all
end
```

I want output like this:

```
<tr>                      
                    <th >#</th>
                    <th >Date</th> 
                    <th >Project name</th>
                    <th >Title</th>
                    <th >User name</th>   #*this from table user*
                    <th >Status</th>
                    <th >Action</th>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell unless you post your models, but assuming the user has an association that points to reimburses you could do it like this:

```
@reimburses = @users.map(&:reimburses).flatten
```

Comment: yes, in users model has_many reimburse and in reimburses model belongs_to user